collection of continuous functions having certain property.
Let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions for n ≥ 1. Suppose for
each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $n(x) \in\mathbb{ N}$ such that $f_{n(x)}(x) = x + n(x).$
Prove that there exists $a < b$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_m(x) = x+m$
for all $x \in [a, b].$
my idea
suppose for all $[a,b]$  type intervals above is not rue then take $[a_1,b_1]$
we can find $x'_1<x^{''}_1$ such that $x'_1,x^{''}_1\in [a_1,b_1]$ with $x'_1\neq x^{''}_1$ and $n(x'_2)\neq n(x^{''}_2)$.
choose another subset $[a_2,b_2]\subset [a_1,b_1]$ such that $x'_1\in [a_2,b_2]$ and $x^{''}_1\notin [a_2,b_2]$
and points $x'_2$ with $x'_2\in [a_2,b_2]$ such that $n(x'_2)\neq n(x^{'}_1)$.
this will give us a sequence ${x'_n}$ which has a convergent subsequence ${x'_{n_k}}$ which converges to $l$ hence
$\lim_{k\to\infty} f_{n(x'_{n_k})}(x'_{n_k}) =\lim_{k\to\infty} (x'_{n_k} + n(x'_{n_k}))=l+n(l)$,
but still unable to move forward

This is an immediate consequence of Baire Category Theorem. Let $A_n=\{x: f_n(x)=x+n\}$. Then each $A_n$ is closed and $\mathbb R=\bigcup_n A_n$. By Baire Category Theorem there exists $m$ such that $A_m$ contains an interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$.

why $A_n $ closed

Because $f_n$ is continuous. [$A_n$ is the inverse image of ${n}$ under the continuous map $f_n(x)-x$. If you prefer, you can also use the definition of closedness using sequences].

ok its good, now
